# Python: setting an array element with a sequence error for my edge detection

Tags: python, arrays

I have the error setting an array element with a sequence and I'm not sure how I can fix it. The line that is triggering the error is:

```
ret[q,l] = (50,255,20)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What I'm trying to do is change every pixel from the thresh array (located edges) in a greyscale image to a green color however I keep getting this error.

Also here is the rest of my edge detect code:

```
def edgeDetect(img, threshold):
    ret = img.copy()
    thresh = []
    h = img.shape[0]
    w = img.shape[1]
    for y in range(1, h-2):
        for x in range(1, w-2):
            gx = 0
            gy = 0
            gx = (img.item(y, x)*0 + img.item(y + 1, x)*0 + img.item(y-1, x)*0 + img.item(y, x+1)*2 + img.item(y, x-1)*-2 + img.item(y+1, x+1)*1 + img.item(y-1, x-1)*-1 + img.item(y+1, x-1)*-1 + img.item(y-1, x+1)*1)
            gy = (img.item(y, x)*0 + img.item(y + 1, x)*-2 + img.item(y-1, x)*2 + img.item(y, x+1)*0 + img.item(y, x-1)*0 + img.item(y+1, x+1)*-1 + img.item(y-1, x-1)*1 + img.item(y+1, x-1)*-1 + img.item(y-1, x+1)*1)
            result = gx**2 + gy**2
            if(result > float(threshold)**2):
                thresh.append([y,x])
    for p in range(len(thresh)):
        print()
        q, l = thresh[p]
        img[q,l] = (50,255,20)
    return ret
```

Comment: Post the exact error message, including the traceback.

Comment: I'll take a guess: use `img[q][l]` instead of `img[q,l]`

Comment: What exactly do you want `img[q,l] = ...` to do? What is `img`? A Python list-of-lists? A 2D-Numpy-Array? Some special image class? Judging from the methods you use on `img` it _seems_ to be a Numpy array, but then `img[q,l]` should work.

Comment: Why set `gx, gy` to 0?

Comment: @tobias_k I used cv2.imread for the image? I think it should be a np array.

Comment: @JohnGordon 

        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFile.py", line 78, in <module>
    img = edgeDetect(img, blur)
  File "testFile.py", line 49, in edgeDetect
    img[q,l] = (50,255,20)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are trying to set a 3-channel value (RGB or BGR if using OpenCV) to a single-channel array (i.e., grayscale).

In other words, what's the shape of the img array? If your image is 256x256 pixels, is the shape (256,256) or (256,256,3)? If the latter, you should be able to set the pixel value (3-tuple) as `img[row,col,:] = (r,g,b)`.

If my assumption that img is only single channel then what you need to do is convert the existing single channel image to 3 channels and then set the color.

OpenCV's cvtColor(...) is an easy way to convert from grayscale images to BGR/RGB, but you can do the same with straight-forward numpy commands.

Comment: You were correct. I was trying to set a 3-channel value to a single channel array and using the cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB), I was able to change the color of the pixels to green. Thank you so much!!